# How to retrieve data from a table with two of the columns in the table with the same value?

Tags: mysql, self-join

```
UserName, UserID, FollowingUserID
'RachelLim', '1003', '1004'
'YunaKim', '1005', '1007'
'AustinLee', '1007', '1005'
'BenChoi', '1010', '1001'
'RebeccaFang', '1009', '1004'
'AliceAng', '1004', '1003'
```

Basically, i want to find rows in which userid = followinguserid. How do i do it using select?

Comment: Is UserID unique?

Comment: *i want to find rows in which userid = followinguserid* Where these fields are to be equal? in ONE record? or you need a record pair where userid in one record is equal to followinguserid in another?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **SELF JOIN** to get result

```
select t1.* 
from my_table as t1
join my_table as t2 on t1.userid = t2.followinguserid
```